# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken return null and getting com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown genrated

Tags: google-drive-android-api, google-authenticator

This my code:
Main Activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener   {

    private static final String TAG = "PlayHelloActivity";
   // This client id
            public static String TYPE_KEY = "997914232893-4f2dggarutugl7r945jblef441mia28f.apps.googleusercontent.com";
         private static final String SCOPE = "audience:server:client_id:"+TYPE_KEY+":api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";

        private String mEmail;
        ProgressDialog  mDialog;

        String providerName;
        private AlertDialog dialog;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getUsername();

        }
         @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT) {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        mEmail = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                        Log.e("email", ""+mEmail);
                        getUsername();

                    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "You must pick an account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_AUTH_ERROR ||
                        requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR)
                        && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    handleAuthorizeResult(resultCode, data);
                    return;
                }

            }


         /** Attempt to get the user name. If the email address isn't known yet,
             * then call pickUserAccount() method so the user can pick an account.
             */
            private void getUsername() {

           if (mEmail == null) {
                    pickUserAccount();
                } else {
                    if (isDeviceOnline()) {
                        new GetNameInForeground(MainActivity.this, mEmail, SCOPE).execute();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "No network connection available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            /** Starts an activity in Google Play Services so the user can pick an account */
            private void pickUserAccount() {
                String[] accountTypes = new String[]{"com.google"};
                Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                        accountTypes, false, null, null, null, null);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
            }
            /** Checks whether the device currently has a network connection */
            private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
                ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }


            private void handleAuthorizeResult(int resultCode, Intent data) {
                if (data == null) {
                  //  show("Unknown error, click the button again");
                    return;
                }
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Retrying");
                    new GetNameInForeground(MainActivity.this, mEmail, SCOPE).execute();
                    return;
                }
                if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                   // show("User rejected authorization.");
                    return;
                }
               // show("Unknown error, click the button again");
            }
            /**
             * This method is a hook for background threads and async tasks that need to provide the
             * user a response UI when an exception occurs.
             */
            public void handleException(final Exception e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (e instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException) {
                            // The Google Play services APK is old, disabled, or not present.
                            // Show a dialog created by Google Play services that allows
                            // the user to update the APK
                            int statusCode = ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException)e)
                                    .getConnectionStatusCode();
                            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(statusCode,
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
                            dialog.show();
                        } else if (e instanceof UserRecoverableAuthException) {
                            // Unable to authenticate, such as when the user has not yet granted
                            // the app access to the account, but the user can fix this.
                            // Forward the user to an activity in Google Play services.
                            Intent intent = ((UserRecoverableAuthException)e).getIntent();
                            startActivityForResult(intent,
                                    REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
}
```

This is requst for getting token :

```
public class GetNameInForeground extends AbstractGetNameTask {

  private static final String REQUEST_CODE_AUTH_GOOGLE_ACCOUNT = null;


public GetNameInForeground(MainActivity activity, String email, String scope) {
      super(activity, email, scope);
  }


  /**
   * Get a authentication token if one is not available. If the error is not recoverable then
   * it displays the error message on parent activity right away.
   */
  @Override
  protected String fetchToken() throws IOException {
      try {
           String token= GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
         return token;

      } catch ( UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {


          mActivity.handleException(userRecoverableException);
      } catch ( GoogleAuthException fatalException) {
         onError("Unrecoverable error" + fatalException.getMessage(), fatalException);
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

      return null;
  }


}
```

If I'm not using client id in scope url then I'll get details of only my account (in which you have register in google developer account)then what is the use of client id.